# Borrowing From Vector

Tags: rust

In this code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut numbers = vec![1, 3, 5, 2, 8, 1];

    // 1 - non-borrow
    let mut largest = numbers[0];
    largest = 20;

    println!("{} {}", numbers[0], largest);

    // 2 - borrow
    let mut largest = &numbers[0];
    largest = &30;

    println!("{} {}", numbers[0], largest);
}
```

1. What is the difference between the non-borrow in `1` and the borrow in `2`?

   - It seems like just the type of `largest` is influenced.
2. Why in `2` does `largest` need to borrow a literal value?
3. Is there a way to actually reference the first value in the vector and change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between the non-borrow in 1 and the borrow in 2?

In case 1, the variable `largest` stores a copy of the value of `numbers[0]`, or `1`. In case 2, the variable `largest` stores a reference (memory address) specifying the place in memory where `numbers[0]` is stored.

> Why in 2 does `largest` need to borrow a literal value?

Because in that case, `largest` is of type `&i32` — a reference to an integer — so you can only assign references-to-integers to that variable.

> Is there a way to actually reference the first value in the vector and change it?

```rust
let largest = &mut numbers[0];
*largest = 30;
```

The key elements here are:

- You must use `&mut`, not `&`, if you want to change anything by-reference.
- You must use the `*` dereference operator to assign to something through a reference. If you don't use `*`, you're just assigning to the variable that holds the reference.